# Why is Dragon Ball Super's animation quality so terrible?

Tags: anime-production, dragon-ball-super

I've been watching the *Dragon Ball Super* series from the release date and I keep hating it more and more. I don't know if you guys have noticed it but all battle animations are terrible.

Here's an example:

[image]

Is there a logical explanation why a 2015 anime is so poorly animated compared to DBZ?

Comment: And that's not even talking about the filler content they put in there... What is Pilaf even doing there? And why did Vegeta become a wimp all of a sudden?!

Comment: I can tolerate the fact that Vegeta is so terrified. It's like a childhood trauma, and he has a wife and a kid now, in my opinion that's acceptable unlike the quality of the animation.

Comment: I don't know if this can be used for an answer, but there is a lot of posts that says that responsible for this is Toei Animations because they have really tide schedule for every show (not only Dragon Ball). So they push all people to work a ton of hours per day and payment it's too low. So that means maybe that these people cannot do good episodes if they have so much work ahead of them.

Comment: @pap If you can find a reliable source that says that, you'd have enough for an answer.

Comment: I find this a normal occurrence for anime that is aired on TV, especially when the studio has tight deadline until the animator has to rush to make it "watchable" (i.e. "ugh, bad animation" vs "there's no battle scene at all!"). Usually there will be DVD and/or BluRay version with most animation errors fixed. However, I just state the general case, which might (or might not) be the case for Dragon Ball Super.

Comment: @Torisuda is this enough: http://kotaku.com/dragon-ball-super-looks-super-crappy-1723059211

Comment: @pap The link you provide 1) doesn't claim Toei has a tight schedule and its employees are overworked & underpaid (there's only a mention by Thomas about the industry in general; his employer is not named) and 2) doesn't claim animators do not have the skill to produce quality work under such conditions (to be honest, this has no discernible bearing on quality of the product as it is the common working condition across all of Japan's industries [i.e. the salaryman] and has always been the case in the anime and especially in the manga industry, yet countless artists have produced quality work)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anime budget does not have anything to do with the year it airs. It's related mostly to the main animation studio and to internal decisions inside the studio.

In the case of Super, I think it's because the studio making it is Toei Animation. I very similar example, if not the same, is the Saint Seiya anime which is currently airing , Soul of Gold. You can look at several episodes where the animation quality drops to substandard levels.

Each animation studio has its own characteristics that end up defining the brand, and quality consistency between titles and during a title run is one of them.
Toei is just not very good with this.

Comment: I don't think the OP was implying that the show should have a higher budget because it's made in 2015; the OP was implying that with the new digital animation technology, it should be possible to make higher quality animation on the same budget. Good point about studio quality varying, though; I've noticed that Gonzo is also pretty awful at maintaining quality across a series.

Comment: Indeed he wasnt. but he made an opened question about the possible reasons behind the low quality, so I tried to explain the rationalization behind it, as well as the known effect from the audience perspective, which is the quality inconsistency between series/episodes that some studios show.

Comment: Toei is the exact same studio that produced _DBZ_ which the OP is comparing _Super_ to (and Toei has produced many, many very high quality TV anime, including fully hand-animated ones before the digital period), so to claim that "Toei is just not very good with this" does not provide a credible reason that 2015 anime production is lower in quality than 1989~1996 anime by the same company.

Comment: I didnt say 'toei isnt good', i said 'consistrncy is a characteristic of animation studios, and toei is known for not being a very much consistent one', there's a significant difference. And it's not just toei, there are several animation studios where you cam see signoficant quality inconsistency between episodes.